# Does pandas read the full data file and stores it in a data frame? Is it efficient to load a 100mb file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I want to load a file of size around 100mb using pandas. I know we can load but I want to know does the file size affects the efficiency of the program. And is there any way to load the file efficiently?

Comment: I generally use a simple heuristic for these sorts of considerations: if it fits in memory on my consumer device, Pandas can work with it fairly efficiently. So far this rule of thumb has not yet failed me - but then again, I do often chunk data files that are larger than a few gigabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I am using Pandas for files with sizes between some kilobytes and a few gigabytes without any problems. As stated [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-pandas-with-large-data-9594dda2ea4c) Pandas is very efficient with data 100MB up to 1GB. Thats pretty much what I observe when using Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the performance is affected and sometimes system gets slow.

You can try to read the data in the form of table or you can also use chunksize. This will improve the efficiency